# Using a forEach loop to overwrite values

Tags: javascript, foreach, discord.js

**Alright so I have a code like so**

```js
giveaways.forEach( x => {
    if (x.extraData) {
      const guild = client.guilds.cache.get(x.extraData.server)
      const channel = guild.channels.cache
        .filter((channel) => channel.type === 'text')
        .first()
      channel.createInvite().then( inv => { // returns promise
     embed.addField(`Join Requirement Giveaway:`, `**[This Server](${inv})**`)
      })
    } else {
      embed.addField(`Normal Giveaway:`,`**[${x.prize}](https://discord.com/channels/${x.guildID}/${x.channelID}/${x.messageID})**`)
    }
  })
```

Where the commented part returns a promise , I am using a forEach loop and I am aware that we are unable to overwrite values in an asynchronus one therefore my embed returns the portion of the loop without the promise, I am looking for a possible solution to this.

Comment: What do you mean by "I am aware that we are unable to overwrite values in an asynchronus one"? Why would this be the case?

Comment: Just to be a bit clear about what I meant with that if you wanna overwrite/add values to a constructor with a promise say 
```var z;
 x.forEach( async y => { z = 1})```
that won't be possible would it be

Comment: @Zero of course this is possible. The issue here is **time**, because besides the Promise nothing else would know **when** this change would happen. *Consider how much your CPU can do in just a few milliseconds*.

Comment: Understood, what is the way to work around it then, except for the answer given below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Promise.all with map

Like this

```
Promise.all(giveaways.map((x) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  // ~~ doing something
  somePromises.then((inv) => {
    embed.addField(/*~~~*/)
    resolve();
  })
})))
  .then(() => {
    // next things..
  });
```

Comment: Right, seems fair, Thanks!

Comment: @Thomas Thanks for reply. I will remove await on the code :)

Comment: Yes, but no. This code is a weird mix of Promises and await and the "new Promise"-antipattern. better use an async function in `map`: `.map(async (x) => { ... const inv = await channel.createInvite(); ... })`